# Why does diatomic oxygen have five filled molecular orbitals, but is considered to have two bonds?

Tags: bond

So I'm taking an introductory chemical physics course and we are covering LCAO-MO.
We learn about the molecular orbitals that arise out of a combination of the two atoms atomic orbitals. This totally makes sense to me, but then we start learning about electron configurations and orbital diagrams. When we get to oxygen the textbook shows that oxygen has 8 electrons each, and when they combine they fill up the σ<sub>1s</sub> σ<sub>2s</sub> σ<sub>2p<sub>z</sub></sub> π<sub>2p<sub>x</sub></sub> π<sub>2p<sub>y</sub></sub> bonding orbitals and the σ*<sub>1s</sub> σ*<sub>2s</sub> antibonding orbitals (with the π*<sub>2p<sub>x</sub></sub> π*<sub>2p<sub>y</sub></sub> antibonding orbitals each half filled). My question is:

#### Why does this result as a double bond?

I see it is partially addressed here: [Molecular Orbital Theory and No. of bonds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19674/molecular-orbital-theory-and-no-of-bonds) 
But what they don't speak to is why there are two filled π<sub>2p</sub> bonding orbitals but only one pi bond. I understand how to calculate bond order but in my understanding thats our approach at reasoning out bond strength, it returns an integer value - it does not really tell me much about the actual bonds themselves. Is the pi bond that results some sort of hybrid between the π<sub>2p<sub>x</sub></sub> and π<sub>2p<sub>y</sub></sub> orbital? If there are two electrons each in the π<sub>2p<sub>x</sub></sub> and π<sub>2p<sub>y</sub></sub> orbitals, how does one electron in each of their respective antibonding orbitals play out in the formation of the bond?
 
Thank you ChemSE community!
*editted to further clarify I am aware of bond order calculations